# Como mantengo mi app actualizada con datos de mi base de datos mysql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos, pyqt

He leído bastante, investigado en varias paginas pero no he podido encontrar respuesta a mi interrogante.
Tengo una aplicación hecha con PyQt, esta misma app sube datos a una base de datos mysql y los descarga cuando uno le indica. Pero la aplicación funciona con varios clientes y estoy tratando de encontrar la manera de mantener actualizado cada cliente con los datos de la base de datos.

Intente hacer un QThread que cada cierto tiempo este realizando una consulta para ver si hay datos nuevos pero se me cuelga por alguna razón (soy nuevo en hilos).

```
class Example(QThread):
    def __init__(self)
        self.bool = True

    def start:
        self.bool = True
        while self.bool:
            print("hola mundo!")

    def stop:
        self.bool = False
```

Es un ejemplo de como estoy usando hilos, el tema es que cuando llamo a Example().start() se me cuelga todo el resto de la aplicación, se congela y únicamente queda imprimiendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según los [desarrolladores](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) de Qt no se recomienda derivar directamente de `QThread` y sobreescribir sus métodos tal y como estas haciendo. Aunque esta práctica esta bastante extendida, existen razones para evitarla en lo posible. Hay muchas alternativas pero, quizás la más directa, sea crear una subclase de `QObject` que actuará como worker y usar el método `moveToThread`.

Recordar que se pueden y se deben usar señales para comunicar los hilos y que **nunca se debe modificar de forma directa un widget desde un hilo**. La interfaz gráfica solo debe ser dibujada y modificada desde el hilo principal. Si desde un hilo secundario hay que actualizar algún componete de la interfaz se usarán señales o cualquier otro método que sea thread-safe(como colas).

Por otro lado, recordar que **`QThread` no se ejecuta en un hilo independiente en si mismo, solo su método `run` lo hace**. `QThread` solo es un contenedor, hay que tener cuidado con esto, cualquier método bloqueante no llamado de forma directa por `run` bloqueará la interfaz.

Un ejemplo de una aplicación completa usando `Qthread` sin usar una subclase de este:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton,  QMainWindow,  QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QObject,  QThread,  QMutex,  pyqtSignal,  QRect

class Worker(QObject):
    candado = QMutex()
    resultado = pyqtSignal(str)
    iniciado = pyqtSignal()
    terminado = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker,  self).__init__()
        self._trabajando = False
        self._abortar = False

    def iniciar(self):
        self.candado.lock()
        self._trabajando = True
        self._abortar = False
        self.candado.unlock()
        self.iniciado.emit()

    def abortar(self):
        self.candado.lock()
        if self._trabajando:
            self._abortar = True
        self.candado.unlock()

    def procesar(self):
        for n in range(60):
            self.candado.lock()
            abortar = self._abortar
            self.candado.unlock()
            self.resultado.emit('Contador desde hilo: {}'.format(n) )
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if abortar:
                self.resultado.emit('Trabajo en hilo abortado')
                break
        else:
            self.resultado.emit('Trabajo completado')

        self.candado.lock()
        self._trabajando = False
        self.candado.unlock()
        self.terminado.emit(True)


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Ejemplo QThread'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        boton_iniciar = QPushButton('Iniciar', self)
        boton_iniciar.move(100,120) 
        boton_iniciar.clicked.connect(self.iniciar_hilo)

        boton_detener = QPushButton('Detener', self)
        boton_detener.move(210,120) 
        boton_detener.clicked.connect(self.detener_hilo)

        self.etiqueta = QLabel(self)
        self.etiqueta.setGeometry(QRect(140, 180,  400, 50))
        self.etiqueta.setText('-------------------------')

        self.hilo = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.hilo)
        self.worker.resultado.connect(self.actualizar_etiqueta)
        self.worker.iniciado.connect(self.hilo.start)
        self.hilo.started.connect(self.worker.procesar)
        self.worker.terminado.connect(self.hilo.quit)

    def iniciar_hilo(self):
        self.worker.iniciar()

    def detener_hilo(self):
        self.worker.abortar()

    def actualizar_etiqueta(self,  datos):
        self.etiqueta.setText(datos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = App()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

La aplicación muestra una interfaz con dos botones y un label. Un botón permite lanzar un hilo, el otro lo detiene. El label muestra la información procesada en el hilo.

El proceso que se ejecuta en el hilo es solo un ejemplo simple, un contador de 0 a 59 con medio segundo de espera entre cada número.

El proceso se puede detener en cualquier momento. Se usa Qt5 (pyqt5) pero la idea es válida par Qt4 (pyqt4), solo habría que cambiar los import en principio:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPushButton,  QMainWindow,  QLabel
from PyQt4.QtCore import  QObject,  QThread,  QMutex,  pyqtSignal,  QRect
```

Se usa un candado para modificar y acceder a las variables de control en el hilo. Posiblemente no sea necesario en este caso en el que, si no me equivoco, son operaciones atómicas. No obstante no es mala práctica proteger las variables, memoria, ficheros, etc compartidos entre hilos.

Captura de la app funcionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay alguna forma comunicar entre hilos objetos que no sean de un tipo primitivo?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no sean de tipo primitivo? ¿Comunicarse con hilos que no son QThread? ¿Comunicar con hilos nativos de Python por ejemplo?

Comment: Creo que con código se explicarme mejor :D me refiero a hacer algo así : ``resultado = pyqtsignal(x_clase)``

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, a vale.... en teoria podrias emitir cualquier tipo python válido o una cadena representando tipos C++ válidos sin problemas. Eso incluye el tipo  `object ` de Python, es decir puedes emitir una instancia de cualquier clase personal creada en Python sin problemas.

Comment: Pues estuve probando el otro día y no me funciono con pyqt4. De ahí que me llevo a pensar que sólo se podían pasar tipos primitivos. Retomaré a ver si indago más está vez, Gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo el manejo de señales en pyqt4 es diferente, lo que comento funciona con total seguridad en pyqt5 pero es posible que esto no sea posible en pyqt4. La verdad es que tendria que mirarlo, cuando tenga un momento probaré a ver cual es la mejor forma de hacer esto. Otra opción podria ser usar una cola para envolver la instancia pero es una idea loca que se me ocurre ahora... Saludos.

Comment: No te preocupes, si no esto se volverá demasiado largo para estar en comentarios y tampoco está muy relacionado con la pregunta. Intentaré algo y si no consigo nada publico una pregunta más especifica. De momento y como siempre tu informacion es de gran ayuda. Y agradezco mucho tu interés por ayudar :)

Comment: He probado el ejemplo que nos compartio FJ Sevilla.Me ha funcionado de maravilla para mi codigo. Gracias por compartir tus conocimientos!

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente te falta el método `run` y un `__init__`, la arquitectura básica de una clase heredada de `QThread` debiera ser más o menos así:

```
class mythread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent:
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self,parent) 

    def run(self):
        # Lógica del thread
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("mythread.start()"),"arrancamos")
        pass
```

Para invocarla desde la clase de la interfaz

```
self.t=mythread(self)
```

Y para conectar las señales del thread y las podamos procesar, conectamos la señal a un método cualquiera, por ej: `thread_start`

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.t, QtCore.SIGNAL("mythread.start()"), self.thread_start)
```

Y obviamente, hay que crear el método `thread_start` en la clase de la interfaz, y procesar los mensajes, para informarlos, o mover una barra de progreso