# pyqt 5 ventana emergente boton parar

Tags: python, pyqt5

Tengo lo siguiente:

al ejecutar el archivo

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog

from PyQt5 import uic

import subvent

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('conexion.ui', self)

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.invocar)
        self.Sub = subvent.Subvent()

    def invocar(self):
        self.Sub.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Principal()
ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

presiono el boton conexion y abre 
**subvent.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import time
class Subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)

        self.valor = 0
        self._auto(self.valor)

        self.boton_parar.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)
        self.boton_inicio.clicked.connect(self.inicio)

    def ocultar(self):

        self.valor = 1
        #self.close()
        #self.linea.setEnabled(False)
        self._auto(self.valor)
    def inicio(self):

        self.valor = 2
        self._auto(self.valor)

    def _auto(self, dato):

       for x in range (0,5):

            if  self.valor == 2:
                #self.caja.setText('inicio')
                self.caja.setText(str('x='))
                print ('vuelta  ', x)
                time.sleep(1)
            elif self.valor == 1:
                #self.caja.setText('parar')
                print ('llego  parar')
                self.close()
                break
```

Les dejo una imagen para  que tengan una idea

[image: les dejo una imagen para que tengan una idea]

Bueno el caso es que al presionar inicio y este corriendo la cuenta de vueltas por ahora solo 5 (pero la idea es que sean mas), pueda parar esa cuenta. 
no he podido lograrlo ya que al ejeutar el programa y darle parar solo lo hace cuando termina de contar.

mientras se ejecuta el for(esta contando), se deshabilitan los botones y ventanas y no me deja presionar parar.

solo se puede al finalizar el for

Comment: Hola omardread, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: vale, gracias amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es el viejo error tan común en la programación de GUIs, estás bloqueando el *main loop* de la app. Toda aplicación tiene un ciclo principal encargado de dibujar la interfaz y de responder a los eventos generados, de iniciar este ciclo se encarga `app.exec_()` precisamente. El *main loop* jamás debe bloquearse o la aplicación quedará congelada y dejará de responder.

`time.sleep` es bloquenate (al igual que `input` por ejemplo), esto quiere decir que no retorna hasta que el tiempo pasado como argumento no a pasado. Cualquier función que no retorne de forma "inmediata" y que no sea ejecutada de forma asíncrona va a bloquear la ejecución del código en ese punto hasta que no retorne.

Si tu app se va a limitar a un contador la opción más simple es prescindir de `time.sleep` y un ciclo `for` y usar [`QtCore.Qtimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5 import uic



class Subvent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('ventana.ui', self)

        self._running = None
        self._vuelta = None

        self.boton_parar.clicked.connect(self.ocultar)
        self.boton_inicio.clicked.connect(self.inicio)

        self._timer = QTimer()
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._auto)


    def ocultar(self):
        self._running = False


    def inicio(self):
        self._vuelta = 0
        self._running = True
        self.caja.setText('Iniciada')
        self._timer.start(1000)


    def _auto(self):
        if self._vuelta <= 5:
            if  self._running:
                self.caja.setText('x = {}'.format(self._vuelta))
                self._vuelta += 1

            else:
                self._timer.stop()
                self.caja.setText('Detenida')
        else:
            self._timer.stop()
            self.close()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en cada "vuelta" piensas hacer alguna tarea que tarde en retornar entonces vas a tener que ejecutarla de forma asíncrona, usando un hilo por ejemplo. Puedes mirarte [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72501/15089) mía a otra pregunta donde como ejemplo se usa un hilo para implementar un contador también.

Comment: Gracias totales, con esto ya puedo detener el arduino.